# Removing height difference

Tags: html, css

So I have a label and a field. But for some reason they don't seem to align. Here's my markup

```
<span class="hash">#</span>
<input type="text" class="hex" maxlength="6">
```

And the CSS.

```
.hex {
width: 385px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.hash {
font-size: 51px;
font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
}
```

I want to align the `#` with the field. I've tried `line-height`, but that didn't work. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/fejoluwu/1/edit) a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `vertical-align:middle` for both the elements:

```
.hex {
    width: 385px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    border: 3px solid black; 
    vertical-align:middle; /* add this */
}
.hash {
    font-size: 51px;
    font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
    vertical-align:middle;  /* add this */
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/fejoluwu/3/)